# I want to read text files from a folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files, instance

In the code Below:

I read from just one text file, but i want to read from multiple files in a folder and then assign the variables and create a new instance of appointment for each file??

```
public bool Load()
    {
        DateTime start  = new DateTime(2000,01,01);
        int length = 0;
        string screenDiscription = "";
        string line;
        int i = 1;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Appointments.txt");

        if (!File.Exists("Appointments.txt"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 1)
            {
                start = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "dd/MM/yyyy HHmm", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
            }
            if (i % 4 == 2)
            {
                length = int.Parse(line);
            }
            if (i % 4 == 3)
            {
                screenDiscription = line;
                apps.Add(new Appointment(start, length, screenDiscription));
            }
            i++;
    }
            sr.Close();
            return true;

    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a database? You can xopy deploy some of them along with your application. SQLite is popular, and I rhink SQLServer compact edition works like this too.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider a format like json where you can easily store several xomplex records within a single file. This is fine if the whole data fits into RAM and you don't multiple concurrent writers.

Answer (score 0):

To get the all the files in a directory use the function `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("directoryPath");` 
Read this page for the documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx